# Mini jack microphone only works in headset

Tags: microphone

This is so weird. I have never seen anything like this before. I have a Kingston HyperX headset. The microphone is detachable and [looks like this](http://www.pcgameware.co.uk/images/Kingston-HyperX-Cloud-detachable-microphone.jpg). When I plug this directly into my PC or USB adapter (with a mini jack for microphone), it does not detect any sound *what so ever*. Literally none.

However, when I plug it into the headset and use the mini jack from the headset, it works just fine. This makes me think that Kingston did something weird with their wiring. I spliced open a mini jack I had laying around, and I tried hooking it up directly to the microphone, but no matter which combination I tried, I couldn't get any sound. I set Windows to listen always, so I heard a lot of jittering and buzzing when I accidentally shorted them. It works just fine with the headset, though.

So this is basically what it comes down to:

[image]

I hope that makes sense. The headset is not powered by USB or anything. How do I make this microphone work in a regular AUX/mini jack port, so I can "ignore" the headset?

Comment: That microphone has a 3 pin plug, while microphones only need the tip and the sleeve, maybe the headset shorts the middle pin (the ring) with the sleeve to activate the microphone.

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas They have 3 pins because of stereo, though... Right?